# Getting only new mail from an IMAP server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, imap

I am writing a client application that fetches emails from an IMAP server and then stores them in a database. The problem is that once I have checked the mail, the next time I only want to download the mail that has arrived since. So if I had checked the server for mail two hour ago, I only want to get the mail that has arrived in the last two hours.

I could use SEARCH with SINCE DATE, but there's no support for time + date could be easily spoofed.

I also tried the RECENT flag, but that doesn't seem to work with gmail (in ruby it shows nil everytime).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You want to use the UniqueId (UID) for the messages. This is specifically why it was created.

You will want to keep track of the last UID requested, and then, to request all new messages you use the message set "[UID]:*", where [UID] is the actual UID value.

For example, lets say the last message feteched had a unique id of "123456". You would fetch

123456:*

Then, discard the first returned message.

UIDs are 'supposed' to be stable across sessions, and never change, and always increase in value. The catch to verify this, is to check the UIDValidity when you select the folder. If the UIDValidity number hasn't changed, then the UIDs should still be valid across sessions.

Here are the relevant parts from the RFC:

2.3.1.1.        Unique Identifier (UID) Message Attribute

A 32-bit value assigned to each message, which when used with the
   unique identifier validity value (see below) forms a 64-bit value
   that MUST NOT refer to any other message in the mailbox or any
   subsequent mailbox with the same name forever.  Unique identifiers
   are assigned in a strictly ascending fashion in the mailbox; as each
   message is added to the mailbox it is assigned a higher UID than the
   message(s) which were added previously.  Unlike message sequence
   numbers, unique identifiers are not necessarily contiguous.

The unique identifier of a message MUST NOT change during the
   session, and SHOULD NOT change between sessions.  Any change of
   unique identifiers between sessions MUST be detectable using the
   UIDVALIDITY mechanism discussed below.  Persistent unique identifiers
   are required for a client to resynchronize its state from a previous
   session with the server (e.g., disconnected or offline access
   clients); this is discussed further in [IMAP-DISC].

**Note: The next unique identifier value is intended to
        provide a means for a client to determine whether any
        messages have been delivered to the mailbox since the
        previous time it checked this value.**

Here is the link with more info:

http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3501.html

What I would do, is also keep track of the InternalDate of the messages downloaded. This way, if you ever lose UID sync, you can at least iterate through the messages, and find the last one you downloaded, based upon the InternalDate of the message.

Comment: yes this is perfect! be sure you run the command "UID 123:*" instead of just "123:*" which returns unexpected results - eg. client.Folders.Inbox.Search("UID 123:*")

Comment: Note that if the last fetched message was deleted in the meantime, discarding the first returned message would result in discarding a message with a higher uid than the last fetched messages uid. Also, I couldn't find anything at all in the RFC about the order of the messages in the fetch response.

Answer (score 4):

There's an imap flag called "seen". Most clients would mark a message seen when viewing the message, so you'd want to iterate over messages on the server which do not have that flag set.

Here's a code snippet which should give you the right idea. The operative bit of course is

```
imap.search(["NOT", "SEEN"]).each do bla.bla.bla
```

Comment: thanks, but my application isn't the only one that has access to that email account. For example, a particular message could have been read in outlook, and thus marked as "seen". Using "seen" would make my application miss it.

Comment: In that case you might just want to iterate over the Message-Id headers in the mail on the server and compare against what you have in the database.

http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/850/10.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you are you able to filter incoming mail into a specific IMAP folder on the server side, your app
can read new messages in that folder and then move them into the standard INBOX folder after it's done.