# PHP imap_search UID SEARCH returns false

Tags: php, imap

I am using PHP's imap functions and want to retrieve emails with a UID > n. This works when searching dates but not UIDs.

```
$imap = imap_open($host, $username, $password);
$emails = imap_search($imap, 'SINCE "8 September 2016"');

var_dump($emails);
```

This outputs:

```
array(16) {
  [0]=>int(30)
  [1]=>int(31)
  [2]=>int(32)
  [3]=>int(33)
  [4]=>int(34)
  [5]=>int(35)
  [6]=>int(36)
  [7]=>int(37)
  [8]=>int(38)
  [9]=>int(39)
  [10]=>int(40)
  [11]=>int(41)
  [12]=>int(42)
  [13]=>int(43)
  [14]=>int(44)
  [15]=>int(45)
}
```

When I try searching by UID:

```
$emails = imap_search($imap, 'UID SEARCH UID 1:*');

var_dump($emails);
```

This outputs:

```
bool(false)
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: `search` is not a `criteria` of `imap_search`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php Maybe you want `TEXT`..

Comment: You just want UID 1:*.

Comment: Sorry, neither of these suggestions work either

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
$emails = imap_fetch_overview($inbox, "1:*", FT_UID);
var_dump($emails);
```

Comment: This works! Any idea why imap_search($inbox, "UID 1:*", SE_UID) doesn't?

Comment: According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php
 "imap_search($inbox, "UID 1:*", SE_UID)" is not valid