# MailKit search IMAP email came after specific UID

Tags: c#, imap, mailkit

I am using MailKit .net library to fetch emails from gmail.

According to [Getting only new mail from an IMAP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084780/getting-only-new-mail-from-an-imap-server) and [IMAP: Search for messages with UID greater than X (or generally, after my last search)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147424/imap-search-for-messages-with-uid-greater-than-x-or-generally-after-my-last-s)

I want to search all emails came after last remembered UID. lets say the last message fetched had a unique id of "123456". I want to search

123456:*

How do I achieve this search in MailKit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are multiple overloads of the `Search` method on an `ImapFolder` in MailKit. You'll want to use one of the overloads that take a `IList<UniqueId>` argument.

Given that, now you'll need to create the list of UIDs to search on. I would recommend taking a look at the `UniqueIdRange` class in the MailKit namespace.

If the last UID that your client program has seen in a previous session was `123456`, you'll actually want your search to start with UID `123457`. In IMAP-speak, `*` is just a wildcard for the "maximum unique id value in the folder". In MailKit, you can just use `UniqueId.MaxValue`.

```
var range = new UniqueIdRange (new UniqueId ((uint) 123457), UniqueId.MaxValue);
```

Now that you have the range `123457:*`, you can perform the search:

```
foreach (var uid in folder.Search (range, query)) {
    var message = folder.GetMessage (uid);
}
```

Comment: What should be there in query in Search (range, query) ? Isn't range itself a query, so why do we need to pass extra param?

Comment: `range` is not a query itself, it is simply a subset of messages to apply your search query to. If you want all of the messages in that range, then you would use `SearchQuery.All` as your query.

Comment: If I use **SearchQuery.All**, will it retrieve all the UIDs to client from server? and after that, it filters down to range subset (at client side)? My goal is to minimize data transfer. I just need UIDs came after the last UID I processed. This can also be done if I retrieve all UIDs from server and then I ignore the UIDs less then the last one I processed. I thought **folder.Search (range, query)** should be performing full filtering operation(range and query both) at server side.

Comment: No, the server will only return the IUDs of the messages within the range. Don't believe me? Check the IMAP protocol logs.

Comment: SearchQuery.All will only match the messages within the specified range as my answer explains. The answer I've given you will produce the absolute minimum traffic possible. Trust me, I know what I'm talking about.

Comment: Hi Folks, I guess this is from long time back but right now when I work the same way I am always getting the last email fetched (in the previous search) if no new emails are in the inbox; basically if I search with range(123457:*), I am still getting the email with uid 123456 if it's the last email in the inbox. Is this supposed to be the correct behavior @jstedfast ?